# Real Time Progress bar with a blockUI doesn't work using primefaces with atmosphere

Tags: sockets, primefaces, progress-bar, push, atmosphere

I have a button and when I press on it, the method obtains data from the data base and show the records in a datatable. The action takes more than 1 minute and I want to show a progress bar (the time is variable)

I found the solution in this page:[Show a real time progress bar in a Html User Dialog](http://answers.axonivy.com/questions/16/show-a-real-time-progress-bar-in-a-html-user-dialog)

The problem is that I show the progress bar, but always is "0%". In the javascript function never enter. And I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

This is my XHTML:

```
    <h:form id="formAllocate">

    <p:panel id="panel" header="Realtime ProgressBar">
        <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Start"
            actionListener="#{scheduleMB.startLongRunningProcess}">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:panel>

    <p:blockUI block="panel" trigger="btn">
        <p:progressBar widgetVar="progressBar" style="width:300px"
            labelTemplate="{value}%">
        </p:progressBar>
        <span id="msg"></span>
    </p:blockUI>

</h:form>

<p:socket channel="/realtime" onMessage="handleProgress"></p:socket>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleProgress(progressJson) {
        alert('begin');
        var progressData = eval("(" + progressJson + ")");
        progressBar.setValue(progressData.progress);
        $("#msg").text(progressData.msg);
    }
</script>
```

This is my Bean:

```
public void startLongRunningProcess(){
    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish("/realtime", "{ 'progress' : 10, 'msg' : 'Extract data'}");

    list =
        getAuxService().findList(userSelected, initDate2,
            endDate2);
  }
```

In the web.xml:

```
<!-- Primefaces PUSH -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In my pom.xml I have this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
    <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using primefaces 5.1, spring 3.2.5, hibernate 4.2.7, java 1.7, primefaces extension 3.0.0

What I'm doing wrong???

Thx for the help and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this (by me) can be found in the (duplicate) [post](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=40905) in the PrimeFaces forum

Summary:

1. @PushEndpoint was missing
2. 4.0 to 5.0 mirgration guide was not followed for the access of the PF widget (widgetName -> PF('widgetName))
3. OP did not know that the increments in the progressbar were to be set each time by publishing an event each time

Comment: You'd better include/blockquote/summarize the actual answer instead of posting only a link. If the link ever rots, then the whole answer is worthless. Stack Exchange answers should be able to stand at its own without ever needing to click a link to an external site in order to figure missing parts -use them at most as support. This way the answer is also valuable to anyone else having the same problem in the future. I.e. the answer should not be OP-centric, but be valuable to anyone having the same problem.

Comment: Adding a summary is fine by me, but if people cross post and the other forum has a lengthy discussion, I'm not sure I want to summarize it...

But I'll do it for this one for now

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites not discussion forums. Have you ever tried searching for answers in a discussion forum? Wasn't you bothered by answers being hard to find if there are lot of irrelevant replies ("comments") on the topic? Wasn't you bothered by answers being hard to find if a reply only contains a link which is either broken or points to another site where you'd have to crawl through all the mess *again* ;) Wasn't you very glad everytime you see a world class answer on a question asked by someone else at a Stack Exchange site? Try contributing the same ;)

Comment: with discussion I meant asking the OP questions to get closer to the problem. Sorry for using the wrong words.  And no I've not had a problem with the sometimes irrelevant posts since in some cases you can actually learn from that. And most of answers to questions I had came from good blogs (yours being in the top 5). I want to share my knowledge, but do not want to post fully preprepared examples. Pointing others in the right direction and having them learn things,along the way (including how to search) is better. If that is in the end not acceptable, then hey… lots of other things to do ;-)

Comment: @jeef: what do you mean? This IS my actual answer and I have (explicitly ) created no code